# spdatasource control in sandboxed solution?

Tags: sandbox-solution

I was surprised to not found the SPDataSource control in sandboxed solution (I simply want to populate a drop down list).

Did I missed something, or is this actually one the limitation of the sandbox ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to MSDN, [SPDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spdatasource.aspx) is not available in Sandboxed solutions.

**Available in Sandboxed Solutions: No**

Comment: hum... I wonder what is the cause of this decision... moreover, SPD can use SPDataSource, I can't understand why such a limitation. Any suggestion to reach the same result ? (instead of manually populating the DDL )

Comment: For some reason just about every class in the Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls namespace is not available in a sandboxed solution.